What does the Raspberry Pi "CPU Load average" numbers actually mean?
Forgive me if this is a dupe of a dupe of a dupe. . .
System:
Raspberry Pi 4 running Buster.
I am running a script that displays "system status" on an Adafruit 128x32 OLED display.  It derives the "CPU load" metric like this:
cmd = "top -bn1 | grep load | awk '{printf \"CPU Load: %.2f\", $(NF-2)}'"

Top reads like this:
load average: 1.60, 1.66, 2.04

Background:
Everybody talks about the Raspberry Pi's "CPU load" figure, but, despite diligent searching, I really haven't seen what that number represents.
A friend of mine on another forum saw a display I was testing that had a "CPU load" of greater than about 1.5, and he asked if I was trying to do crypto-mining!
Htop tells me that the CPUs aren't anywhere near maxed, memory usage is OK, swap hasn't been touched, and - by all the indications I know of - things are just wonderful.
Question:
So, what does the "CPU Load" metric actually tell me?


Everybody talks about the Raspberry Pi's "CPU load" figure, but, despite diligent searching, I really haven't seen what that number represents.

Probably because they aren't really "Raspberry Pi figures" but a universal linux metric (actually they predate linux and are used more widely than that).  If you had searched "linux load average" you would no doubt have found thousands of pages -- which is why you should always consider the broadest possible context, not the most restrictive, when researching stuff like this.
Anyway, in a nutshell, from man proc under /proc/loadavg, these are:

figures giving the number of jobs in the run queue (state R) or waiting for disk I/O (state D) averaged over 1, 5, and 15 minutes

"Jobs" in this context are processes or process threads (I do not think that includes kernel threads, but I am not sure).  "Running" means active on a processor, so in theory at any given instance there should't be more of those than the number of cores, but it also includes processes waiting on I/O.  Since it is an average, this means, eg., a load average of 0.5 on a single core system is the same as saying the CPU usage averaged over the time period was 50%.

A friend of mine on another forum saw a display I was testing that had a "CPU load" of greater than about 1.5, and he asked if I was trying to do crypto-mining!

This implies the CPU usage for averaged for all cores was 37.5% (150/4).

This is actually dating back to Unix. Linux just emulated it.

Yes, that's sort of what I meant by "used more widely", added a bit of clarification.  Doesn't seem to be part of the  POSIX standard though (at least by a quick search).
